# GraphQL types, generics and NestJS Type<>: not assignable to Type<>

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-generics, graphql-js

I am trying to call this definition:

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { Type } from '@nestjs/common';

export function createFilterClass<T extends typeof GraphQLScalarType>(
  FilterType: Type<T>
) {
  // ...
}
```

But all my attempts are failing:

```
import { GraphQLString } from 'graphql';
import { createFilterClass } from './filter-class';

const c = createFilterClass(GraphQLString);

/* Argument of type 'GraphQLScalarType<string, string>' is
   not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<typeof GraphQLScalarType>'.

   Type 'GraphQLScalarType<string, string>' is missing the following
   properties from type 'Type<typeof GraphQLScalarType>':
   apply, call, bind, prototype, and 4 more. ts(2345)
*/
```

```
const c = createFilterClass(GraphQLString);

/* Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to
   parameter of type 'Type<typeof GraphQLScalarType>'.

   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type<typeof GraphQLScalarType>'. ts(2345)
*/
```

Note that I need to do `Type<T>` inside of `createFilterClass`, because otherwise this line will fail:

```
    @Field(() => FilterType, { nullable: true }) // Argument of type '{ nullable: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FieldOptionsExtractor<T>'. ts(2345)
    myField?: T;
```

Comment: could you provide simple working example?

Comment: Here is a sample project: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/simeoncode/nestjs-type-issue/master

Comment: can't load it.. it keeps crashing

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to get this to compile, by doing:

```
createFilterClass<T extends GraphQLScalarType>(FilterType: T) { ... }
```

in combination with this wicked cast:

```
@Field(() => FilterType.constructor as Type<T>, { nullable: true })
```